# Define the cons (::) operator for custom collections

Tags: f#

I am using the fairly popular [FSharpx.Collections](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/) package, and in particular the [NonEmptyList](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-nonemptylist-1.html) type.

This type provides the `NonEmptyList.cons` function, but I want to use the `::` operator as with regular `List`, i.e. `head :: tail`. Since `tail` must already be a `NonEmptyList<'a>`, there shouldn't be any conflict with `List`'s `::`operator.

However, it seems I cannot define the operator. This:

```
let ( :: ) h t = NonEmptyList.cons h t
```

results in a compilation error:

```
Unexpected symbol '::' in pattern. Expected ')' or other token.
```

I know that `::` is not quite in the same category as other operators, but I don't fully understand *how*. So I tried a few things more or less at random, such as replacing `::` with `op_cons` and the like, without success.

Am I missing something, and is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx), colon cannot actually be used in operator name. This seems to contradict [the F# specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.1/FSharpSpec-3.1-working.docx) from FSharp.org, I'm not sure what's going on there. But we can verify that in FSI:

```
> let ( >:> ) a b = a+b
Script.fsx(1,7): error FS0035: This construct is deprecated: ':' is not permitted as a character in operator names and is reserved for future use
```

If you look at [how `List<'T>` is defined](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/0313094fa5d19fd871c83e7e45c35d1fad65daf9/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3493), you'll find that `(::)` is not actually an operator, but a *case constructor*:

```
type List<'T> =
  | ( [] )
  | ( :: ) of Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list
```

And sure enough, you can define your own DU type with that as constructor name:

```
> type A = 
>   | ( :: ) of string * int
>   | A of int
> 
> let a = "abc" :: 5

val a : A = Cons ("abc",5)
```

Now, oddly, if I try to use another operator-ish-looking name as case constructor, I get this error:

```
> type A = | ( |> ) of string * int
Script.fsx(1,14): error FS0053: Discriminated union cases and exception labels must be uppercase identifiers
```

Which means that `(::)` is somehow *special* (and so is `([])`, by the way).

So the bottom line seems to be - no, you can't do that.
But why do you even need to? Can you, perhaps, settle for a more acceptable operator name, which would still express the semantics of "cons" - like, say, `(<+>)`?