# How can I use a symbols in my own definition of list

Tags: f#

I have my own definition of list, that replaces `[]` by `Empty`, `::` by `Cons`, and `@` by `++`.

How can I use similar symbols like these (`[]`, `::`) on my own definition?

```
type 'T MyList =
| Empty  
| Cons of 'T * 'T MyList 

let rec (++) xs ys =
    match xs, ys with
    | Empty, _ -> ys  
    | Cons (head, tail), _ -> Cons (head, tail ++ ys)

let a = Cons (1, Cons (2, Empty))  
let b = Cons (3, Cons (4, Cons (5, Empty)))
let c = a ++ b 

printfn "%A" c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I could say just overload the operators [according to the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading):

```
type MyList<'a> with
    static member op_Cons (value, list) =
           Cons(value, list)
    static member op_Append (list1, list2) =
           concat list1 list2
```

and be done with it. But - `::` is unique in that it's not actually implemented as an operator, but as a discriminated union constructor, and this is how the `List` type is defined.

You could replace the `Cons` with `(::)` to make it work like expected.

```
type 'T MyList =
| Empty  
| (::) of 'T * 'T MyList
```

Unfortunately, `[]`, `@` are special. 
In fact [the definition](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L142) of `List.append` is

```
 let append list1 list2 = list1 @ list2
```

...and not the other way around.
Although, according to spec all it should take to implement `@` is

```
type MyList<'a> with
    static member op_Append (list1, list2) = concat list1 list2
```

in practice, for

```
let list = (Cons(1, Empty)) @ (Cons(2, Empty))
```

the compiler would complain about them not being list types.

It's perfectly fine if you do something like

```
static member op_BitwiseAnd (list1, list2) =
       concat list1 list2
```

and

```
let list = (Cons(1, Empty)) &&& (Cons(2, Empty)) //this compiles
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297544/define-the-cons-operator-for-custom-collections) by Fyodor Soikin.